# How to convert CSV to fixed-width columns saved in different tabs in Emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

I have this set of numbers, i want to use CSV to fixed-with-column in emeditor to split as shown in the image below.
[image]

Please, how  best can i go about this?

I just need the first 8 digits.

I will appreciate kind gesture.

Answer (score 1):

You almost figured it out.

Change to Normal Mode. You want to convert from fixed width to CSV. Change Convert to to Comma separated. Set Column Widths to 8. Then press Convert Now.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, i got it right now.. Yes you were right, i was close. Thanks so much.